# How to pass 2D array of integer type to the Web API using POST

Tags: arrays, .net, post, webapi

I need to pass an 2D array of any size, say a chess board, to a .net Web API controller action and need to test it with POSTMAN too.

The POST method needs to be used for posting the matrix.

Something like..

```
[1,2,3,4]
[1,0,1,0]
[0,1,0,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method could accept collection of collections

```
[HttpPost("post-numbers")]
public object PostNumbers([FromBody] IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> numbers)
{
    return numbers;
}
```

Just send in request body json like

```
[[1,2,3,4],[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1]]
```